# Resizing image width to 100% of container size - persistent space below image

Tags: css

I'm trying to sit an image inside a container DIV that it is otherwise too large for, using

```
max-width: 100%
```

in the CSS to resize it. However, no matter what I adjust, there's a small white space at the bottom. How do I get rid of that so that the DIV border and image fit perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/SC8v9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a `display: block;`on your image.

http://jsfiddle.net/SC8v9/25/

Answer (score 1):

Give the image `float:left` too.

Comment: It works in this case but if you add other elements it can produce unexpected behavior.